# Django: how to use a queryset and display results in a template?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm struggling with Django QuerySets. This is a JSON dump of my Database with data:

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "label_number": "1",
        "label_type": "A",
        "label_desc_nl": "NL Text",
        "label_desc_en": "EN Text",
        "label_desc_de": "DE Text",
        "label_desc_pl": "PL Text",
        "label_desc_es": "ES Text",
        "label_desc_fr": "FR Text",
        "label_desc_it": "IT Text",
        "label_desc_pt": "PT Text",
        "label_desc_cs": "CS Text"
    },
    "model": "myapp.labels",
    "pk": 1
},
{
    "fields": {
        "label_number": "1",
        "label_type": "B",
        "label_desc_nl": "NL Text",
        "label_desc_en": "EN Text",
        "label_desc_de": "DE Text",
        "label_desc_pl": "PL Text",
        "label_desc_es": "ES Text",
        "label_desc_fr": "FR Text",
        "label_desc_it": "IT Text",
        "label_desc_pt": "PT Text",
        "label_desc_cs": "CS Text"
    },
    "model": "myapp.labels",
    "pk": 2
}
]
```

So let's say I want to get the data from "label_desc_fr" WHERE label_number is 1 AND label_type = B. I tried to build and execute a QuerySet in my view like so:

```
q1 = labels.objects.filter(label_number="1")
q1 = q1.filter(label_type="B")

return render(request, 'frontend/base_home.html', {'q1' : q1})
```

The page loads without errors. Now I'm trying to access the data from my template like so:

```
{{q1.label_desc_fr}}
```

Nothing is shown. :( I searched for a way for a queryset to display all vars {{q1.?}} but I couldnt find a way to do this. The Django docs are, in my eyes, clear about creating QuerySets but not so mutch about how to retrieve them from a template. Now I'm wondering, how do I retrieve my results in my template?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You've asked about querysets, but seem to have forgotten that `q1` *is* a queryset; ie it's a container of multiple Label instances. You need to iterate over that container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing to `q1` in template, and it is your complete QuerySet, it is not an single object. I think this should work:

```
q1 = labels.objects.filter(label_number="1", label_type="B")

return render(request, 'frontend/base_home.html', {'q1' : q1})
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for q in q1 %}

    {{ q.label_desc_fr }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch, that works indeed! I felt I was close, your solution finished it, thanks. :)